# How to get list of live video broadcasts using youtube api v3

Tags: youtube-api

I'm having an hard time trying to figure out how I can get a list of videos that are live for a given channel. For instance for this channel:

https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC4R8DWoMoI7CAwX8_LjQHig

I can get the videos from the uploads playlist or any playlist without any issue. However, I can't figure out how to get a list of live broadcasts.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Solved by using:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list

There, you can filter by channelId and filter by live only if you add type=video and eventtype=live.

Thanks anyway

Comment: Thanks man. Yeah you would think "liveBroadcasts" or "liveStreams" or videos.list. Search seems to be the go to utility.